# screen shell keeps getting interrupted with output messages

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port

I connected to my tv box through a UART port on the chip and established a serial connection using screen like this:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

When I hit enter I get shell access and ability to interact with the operating system. Hoever everytime something is printed on the screen the shell gets interrupted and whatever i was typing gets cleared, then I would have to press enter again and start typing the command all over again.

How do I prevent this behavious?

Comment: Since you're using `screen`, can't you just press `^A^L` to force the terminal to be redrawn and get rid of whatever it was that the kernel is presumably crapping out to the serial port?

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I keep getting this message `sending discover...` every few seconds and it messes up whatever command i was typing.